# ¿Como buscar todos los resultados posibles en una consulta web?

Tags: javascript, html, lista, buscador

les agradezco mucho vuestra ayuda.

Necesito saber si existe un Código para buscar todos los resultados posibles en una barra de consultas web. Dejo un ejemplo para que quede claro:

En el buscador coloco por ejemplo "Azul" y me trae un listado con todo lo que contiene "Azul", pero me gustaría que con un Código o carácter especial, me pueda traer el listado con todos los colores.

Dejo este ejemplo para simplificar la consulta, ya que en realidad lo que ando buscando es más complejos.

Ya intenté cosas básicas como usar un *, dejar vacío el campo, y todos los caracteres del teclado y no funciona.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Lo que pides, no existe como una generalidad, hay convenciones, por ejemplo, una cadena vacía, debiera traer todos los registros (sin filtro), y luego tu programas el filtrado para que funcione de esa manera. Si no te queda claro con eso, publica el código que usas para filtrar, de otra manera no se puede responder. Para más información lee [ask] y [mcve].

Comment: No me queda muy claro si estas trabajando en el backend del buscador, o estas trabajando con un buscador ya existente. ¿Podrías añadir un poco más de contexto?

Comment: @jachguate hola amigo, gracias por responder, como se puede hace una "cadena vacía", disculpa lo básico de mi consulta, es que no soy experto.

En el buscador de la web, al buscarlo con la herramienta inspeccionar elemento aparece este Código en el campo de búsqueda:

"modelo":"chevrolet"

Al realizar la búsqueda, me trae todo los modelos chevrolet, pero lo que busco es poder colocar algún carácter o Código, para que me traiga todo los modelos de todas las marcas.

No se si me explico mejor, te agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: @Juan_m_2 hola amigo, gracias por responder, no soy muy experto. 
Estoy buscando información de autos en una web que tiene un buscador donde se puede una marca de autos y trae como resultado un listado de modelos de esa marca. es poder colocar algún carácter o Código, para que me traiga todo los modelos de todas las marcas.  El Código del buscador es así: "modelo":"chevrolet". En donde dice chevrolet, ¿ se puede colocar algún código para que me traiga todas las marcas y no solo una en especifico?

Comment: Hola. Pues eso depende de la implementación de la pagina de la cual no mencionas el nombre.No hay ninguna norma al respecto para las barras de busqueda, y estará diseñada tal y como haya decidido el propietario y/o el diseñador de la web

Comment: @Mauro, vos estás programando la web? o estás usando una Web que ya existe? Si tu caso es el segundo, estás pidiendo ayuda en el sitio equivocado. Si tu caso es el primero, una cadena vacía es eso, simplemente un campo en blanco, que va a tener como valor una cadena de cero caracteres de largo: `""`. En muchos casos, si el campo se deja en blanco, no aplicas ese filtro, y como efecto, devolves todos los registros.